# How do I return an element from a multi-character atom in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

Suppose I define an "x" and assign to it the value 'Hello (which is an atom type in Scheme):

```
(define x 'Hello)
```

Is there any way for me to return the second element of the atom, i.e, I want to return the letter 'e' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the whole string to a list and then only picking the character you need will produce unnecessary garbage to be collected. It's more efficient to use `string-ref`:

```
(string-ref (symbol->string 'Hello) 1) => #\e
```

If you need a string instead of a character, like was mentioned in the above comment by Sylwester, you can convert that to a string by wrapping it in a call to `(string)`. Alternatively:

```
(substring (symbol->string 'Hello) 1 2) => "e"
```

Answer (score 0):

When `'hello` is evaluated it is a singleton symbol with name `hello`. You can get the string representation from `symbol->string`

```
(symbol->string 'hello) ; ==> "hello"
```

Now a string is a sequence of chars:

```
(string->list "hello") ; ==> (#\h #\e #\l #\l #\o)
```

You can get the second char by using `list-ref` with argument 1 (first is index 0) or the usual `cxr`.

```
(list-ref '(#\h #\e #\l #\l #\o) 1) ; ==> #\e
```

If you want a string with one letter you need to make a list with one elmenet and convert it from `list->string`

```
(list->string (list #\e)) ; ==> "e"
```

If you want to have a symbol with only one letter, you use `string->symbol`

```
(string->symbol "e") ; ==> e
```

I'm not exactly sure what you want, but if you piece all or some of these together I bet you can make what you want.

Comment: Use `(string #\e)` instead of `(list->string (list #\e))`